# Application self uninstalls

Tags: applications, internal-storage, data-recovery, uninstallation

I have a Galaxy S4, Eu version, not rooted updated a few days ago to Lollipop.

Today 2 strange things happened:
The phone was connected to charging cable but charge was interrupted when it was at about 80%, this morning I found it at 64% (checked on battery graph).

One app that I use daily, installed in main memory disappeared from home and from installed apps. If I search for it on play store it proposes to install it, not to open it.

I do not know if the 2 things are related. I did not uninstalled any app in the last few days and I am sure that yesterday the missing app was there perfectly working.

Do you think there is a chance to recover the data of the app? I tried to browse phone memory (connected to pc) but I cannot find anything. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: if that app was installed on sd-card and if the sd-card is removed, then app won't be shown as installed. Check if you removed sd-card and your app was installed sd-card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an app cleaner, like 360 security or cleaner app? If so, uninstall it because some cleaner apps delete the apps. I have same issue: no app in home screen, but the apps data is in the folder `Android`/`obb` or `data`.

1. Uninstall Cleaner apps
2. Delete the `.obb` file in `Android` folder and reinstall again.